# Set content-type when performing GET using Alamofire 4

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, content-type

All I want to do is make a simple GET request using Alamofire 4 but set the content-type to application/json

I cannot see a way of doing it on the request. How do I do this.

I thought this would work but it doesn't.

```
Alamofire.request("https://dummy.com/dummy",
                           method: .get,
                           parameters: nil,
                           encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                           headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response 
}
```

I need to do this so that the service I am calling will return the data as JSON rather than XML. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `headers` for that, create dictionary and set it with `headers` with Alamofire `request`.

```
let header = ["content-type" : "application/json"]

Alamofire.request("https://dummy.com/dummy",
                       method: .get,
                       parameters: nil,
                       encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                       headers: header).responseJSON {
        response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much indeed Nivrav D, I could not see the woods for the trees.

Comment: @rideintothesun Welcome mate :)